# Symfony2 Doctrine2 / Memory management

Tags: php, symfony

When I tried to request the payment page (same server), I get a blank page and when I refresh it, all is displayed properly.

Any idea?

Comment: Without some detailed info I will have to consult my crystal ball to try to give you an answer :-)

Comment: "the payment page" - which one? You've not provided context. "same server" - same as which server? I'm voting to close at the moment, please add real detail to this. Have you checked your logs? Is this on your development machine or a remote host? What sort of host is it - shared or VPS/dedicated? Why do you think this is a memory management issue?

Comment: Blank (white) page usually means a webserver error. In your case its probably something like a timeout, or out of allowed memory.
Best solution is to use app_dev.php, that will show you the error, or check your webserver error logs.

Comment: thanks gnay,
Indeed, it is a timeout problem, but how can i rectify it ?

Answer (score 0):

If your having a timeout problem you have 2 options:

1. Increase it via php.ini

   **max_execution_time = 90**
2. add this to your app.php or app_dev.php file.

   **ini_set('max_execution_time', 90)**;

The time is in seconds. Good luck.